# Reserving memory using malloc in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I would like to reserve memory for 3 int arrays in C. All are int types.
Array a is size n, array b is size m and array c is size m.

I have following idea:

```
void *c;
int *a;
int *b;
int *m;

m = malloc((n + m + m +1) * sizeof(int));
a = n;
b = a + m;
c = b + m;

free(m);
```

When I try to acces to some of them using syntax for example

```
a[i] =
```

I got segmentation fault error.

Here is complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *c;
int *dretve;
int *stol;
int *rez;

int n;
int m;


void *Rezerviraj(void *x){
    int c = *((int*)x);
    printf("Ušo u funkciju rezerviraj\n");
//  sleep(10);
    printf("Gotov sam!");
}

int Provjeri(){
    int i;
//  for(i = n; i < m+n; i++)
//      if(stol[i] == 1)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    n = atoi(argv[1]);
    m = atoi(argv[2]);
    int f = 4;

    int i = 0;

    pthread_t thr_id[2];

    c = malloc((n + m + m + 1) * sizeof(int) + n * sizeof(pthread_t));
    dretve = n;
    stol = dretve + m;  
    rez = stol + m; 

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", dretve[i]);   

    pthread_create(&thr_id[1], NULL, Rezerviraj, &f);
    pthread_join(thr_id[1],NULL);

//  pthread_create(&thr_id[1], NULL, Rezerviraj,&f);
//  pthread_join(thr_id[1],NULL);
//  free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain me what is mistake and how can I fix it?
Many thanks!

Comment: where is the _array_?

Comment: How can I make it using malloc? @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: Please pos a [MCVE]. Otherwise we can only guess what is wrong.

Comment: `a = n;`  .... `c = b + m;`...`free(c);`...please re-read the C book.

Comment: @zuma freankly speking, your question is unclear to me.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh what is unclear for you?

Comment: @zuma please stop editing details in your question. Post the complete program that gives you the  segmentation fault error.

Comment: `m` is used as a size and a pointer?  Best to post true code.

Comment: @zuma starting from `a = n;`...then the whole thing renders unclear...

Comment: `int *m;` + `m = malloc((n + m + m +1) * sizeof(int));`: You can't just use `m` and expect the results to be consistent. `m` is not initialized, and `n` isn't declared in the code you provided.

Comment: Turn on/up compiler warnings and fix them! Pointers and `int` values cannot be used interchangably.

Comment: Edited @Michael Walz

Comment: Have I [seen this before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40548598/segmentation-fault-error-in-c-code) ?

Comment: What is your program supposed to do ? Also it would be helpful to post code with english variable names and english text, most people here don't understand serbo-croatian (or whatever). Your code doesn't make any sense to me, at least without explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allocate memory for 3 arrays *of the same type*,

```
int *a_array;
size_t a_count = foo();

int *ba_array;
size_t b_count = foo();

int *c_array;
size_t c_count = foo();

a_array = malloc(sizeof *a_array * (a_count + b_count + c_count));
b_array = a_array + a_count;
c_array = b_array + b_count;

// code uses a_array, b_array, c_array
... 

// When done with all 3, only 1 free() call
free(a_array);
```

Comment: Many thanks! Can you explain me what is foo() and size_t?

Comment: @zuma  `foo()` is _some function_ that returned a value in order to assign `a_count, b_count, ...`.  `size_t` is the unsigned  type best used for array indexing and size demineralizations.  `int` may be to narrow.

Comment: @zuma Recommend to avoid combining allocation for differing types as in `(n + m + m + 1) * sizeof(int) + n * sizeof(pthread_t)`.  It _is_ do-able, but requires additional code/checks for aliment.